# imageView background is not updated

Tags: ios, uiimageview

My app has a `UIImageView` as background, which I had `background.png`.

Today, I got a new resource and updated it -- removed the old file(delete), and added the new file.

To my surprise, the first time I run it, it's still showing the old image somehow. And every second time, it shows the new image.

I tried to clean, rebuild, didn't help. I even tried to remove the entire "DerivedData" folder, still doesn't help.

Anyone knows this problem?

Comment: Delete the app from the device/simulator. In Xcode, do a clean build. The proper image should now appear.

Comment: Thanks, rmaddy. I tried that but it's still the same. I noticed though that looks like inside XCode, it's still showing the old one to me.

Comment: You can change your new image name OR just right click on image and then select show in finder and delete it and add it again.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue before, it happend when I had two files with the same name added to my project. You can do a search for it in the project navigator and see if you can find the extra file.

You can also select your project in the project navigator, select your target and go the the Build Phases and see if you have multiple references to the same file name in the Copy Bundle Resources section.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, if it has solved your issue.

Comment: sorry, just came back to this. How can I accept the answer? Sorry